# Change formatted address order no longer working

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

Something appears to have changed in the new version of WooCommerce, this snippet to change the order of the items in a formatted address used to work fine....

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_order_formatted_billing_address' , 'woo_custom_order_formatted_billing_address' );

/**
 * woo_custom_order_formatted_billing_address
 *
 * @access      public
 * @since       1.0 
 * @return      void
*/
function woo_custom_order_formatted_billing_address() {

    $address = array(
        'first_name'    => $this->billing_first_name,
        'last_name'     => $this->billing_last_name,
        'company'       => $this->billing_company,
        'address_1'     => $this->billing_address_1,
        'address_2'     => $this->billing_address_2,
        'city'          => $this->billing_city,
        'state'         => $this->billing_state,
        'postcode'      => $this->billing_postcode,
        'country'       => $this->billing_country
    );

    return $address;

}
```

But now it returns the following error...

Fatal error: Using $this when not in object context in

Can anyone point me in the right direction of either what is going wrong or an alternative way of achieving it?

Answer (score 1):

I'm seeing this example on the internet, but I don't know if it ever worked. First of because in `'woocommerce_order_formatted_billing_address'` filter, that is applied in `class-wc-order.php` file, two arguments are provided, `$address` ARRAY, and a reference to current `WC_Order` OBJECT. But your definition of the filter function does not provide any arguments. Second, error that you receive describes the problem very accurately, pseudo-variable `$this` is available from within an object context, but your global function is not part of any object.

Enough with technicalities, the definition should look like this:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_order_formatted_billing_address' , 'woo_custom_order_formatted_billing_address', 10, 2 );

function woo_custom_order_formatted_billing_address( $address, $wc_order ) {

    // make the changes to $address array here
    // use for example, $wc_order->billing_first_name, instead of $this->billing_first_name

    return $address;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

@Eolis' answer doens't work for me, because Woocommerce applies `WC()->countries->get_formatted_address( $address )` and this functions erases my new fields added to array on `add_filter`, so my solution is add field to previous field (first_name):

```
add_filter('woocommerce_order_formatted_billing_address', 'my_order_formatted_billing_address', 10, 2);
function my_order_formatted_billing_address($address, $wc_order) {
    $billing_last_name_2 = get_post_meta( $wc_order->id, '_billing_last_name_2', true );
    $address = array(
        'postcode'      => $wc_order->billing_postcode,
        'last_name'     => $wc_order->billing_last_name,
        //\n force break line
        'first_name'    => $wc_order->billing_first_name . "\n" . $billing_last_name_2,

        'address_1'     => $wc_order->billing_address_1,
        'address_2'     => $wc_order->billing_address_2,
        'city'          => $wc_order->billing_city,
        'state'         => $wc_order->billing_state,

        'country'       => $wc_order->billing_country
    );
    return $address;
}
```